# How do you fire onItemClickListener when you also have onTouchListener?

Tags: android, ontouchlistener, onitemclicklistener

I'm following [this tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html), except I'm trying to add a "touch" aspect to each of the images.

So as you can see, `HelloGridView` is exactly the same as the tutorial:

```
public class HelloGridView extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

        gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(HelloGridView.this, "" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

For `ImageAdapter`, I added an `onTouchListener`:

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;

    // create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ImageView imageView;
        if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
            imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(300, 300));
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
        } else {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }

        imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);

        imageView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) { 
                if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    Log.v("log_tag", "MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN");
                    return true;
                } else if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                    Toast.makeText(mContext, "ACTION_UP", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Log.v("log_tag", "MotionEvent.ACTION_UP");
                    return false;
                } else {
                    return false; 
                }
            } 
        }); 

        return imageView;
    }
}
```

The problem is, whenever I touch one of the images, the `onTouchListener` fires in `ImageAdapter`, but not the `onItemClickListener` in `HelloGridView`.

I want `onItemClickListener` to fire on `ACTION_UP`, hence I return false if the event is `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP` and true if its `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN`.

From my understanding, if I return true then the `onTouchListener` consumes the event and it finishes. But if I return false, then the `onTouchListener` doesn't consume the event, and it's passed on to `onItemClickListener` in `HelloGridView`.

Unfortunately, the event ONLY gets passed on to `HelloGridView` if I return false when the event is `ACTION_DOWN`. However, when I do that, `ACTION_UP` never gets executed. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong and how I can fix it? If my question wasn't clear, please let me know and I'll try to clarify! :)

Answer (score 1):

Code for this is

```
@Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        switch(event.getAction())
        {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

            break;         
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

            break;   

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

            if(!mIsTouchHandeled){
                int position = mChatListView.pointToPosition((int) event.getX(), (int) event.getY());
                if(position!=ListView.INVALID_POSITION){
                    mChatListView.performItemClick(mChatListView.getChildAt(position-mChatListView.getFirstVisiblePosition()), position, mChatListView.getItemIdAtPosition(position));
                }
            }
            break;
        }           
        //       return super.onTouchEvent(event);       


        return false;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The OnItemClickListener only gets fired on Action.Down.

Just do the following:
get rid of the OnItemClickListener and replace it with your own Method. Something like "`public void myOnItemActionUp(View view, int pos)`" - whatever.

Pass a reference of your `HelloGridView` to  the ImageAdapter, and call `mHelloGridView.myOnItemActionUp(v, position)` in your OnTouchListener `if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)`.